# Java socket readLine() method strange behavior

Tags: java, bufferedreader, serversocket

I have the following code snippet in a socket server for testing.

```java
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)){

    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Received `exit`... closing client " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Received: " + input);
        out.println("OK");
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When i send a line to it with white space e.g. **Hello World**, it only prints **Hello**. It seems that `readLine()` method behaves like the line is terminated when reading white space.

Is it a character encoding issue or what? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you sending that `Hello World`?

Comment: I have a simple client who connects to the listening socketserver port and then i type in cmd.

Comment: You sent it as two lines. No other possibility. `readLine()` does not behave as claimed here. Post your sending code.

Comment: This is how i send lines to my server socket. In a while (true) loop... `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 out.println(keyboard.next());` Maybe Scanner class misbehaves when sending white space?

Comment: Exactly as predicted. `Scanner.next()` gives you the next token, not the next line. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, you mentioned how you send the data:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
out.println(keyboard.next());
```

And indeed the `Scanner.next()` call returns each word separately, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, **which by default matches whitespace**.

Naively, you might expect that you'd see `Hello` on the server immediately after you type the space. That doesn't happen because the input stream is line-buffered by default, so the `Scanner` doesn't see any input until you press Enter.

To read input line by line, you don't need a `Scanner`; simply wrap `System.in` in a `BufferedReader` and use its `readLine()` method.

Comment: Scanner's `nextLine()` method (instead of `next()`)  works as intended. Thanks for your help!